# How to create a 3D view just like BimViews using Java?

Tags: ifc, bim

I am new to the plugin development of **BimClientServerLib.**
I have to create a plugin/service where i just need the 3D view and get all the information, so that if i push some information like *simulate Door_1* it should be highlighted in the 3D View.I have used the [[BimServerClientLib](https://github.com/opensourceBIM/BIMserver/wiki/BimServerClient)] to check in the project and retrieve some information like get all levels or get all detectors with existing BimViews as 3D viewer and the BIMServerClientLib as a separate Java service.Also, if i use the BimViews which is in Java script how do i push information with the service in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [BIMSurfer](https://github.com/opensourceBIM/BIMsurfer). Download the project into any server (like tomcat), then navigate to the index.html. They have two [examples](https://github.com/opensourceBIM/BIMsurfer/tree/master/examples), local one without a BIMServer and another with a connection to BIMServer.

You can adjust their BIMServer example to load your project and for highlighting a specific element, you can the provided library methods (available on the BIMSurfer github main page).

```
bimSurfer.setSelection({ids: ["object3", "object2", "object4", "object6"], selected: true });
```

Goodluck.